# Using gulp instead of nodejs in IntelliJ ignores breakpoints

Tags: node.js, debugging, intellij-idea, gulp, breakpoints

I have inherited a project running gulp+nodejs. I am trying to use IntelliJ in Windows as my IDE.

If I set my runtime configuration to use "node.js" as its type, I have no problem hitting breakpoints and debugging. However, if I use "gulp.js" as the run type, breakpoints are ignored (and I can essentially never debug). I also tried using Node.js configuration and setting the JS file to node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js instead of server/run.js . This seems to have the exact same problem.

Any thoughts on how I could fix this?

Comment: You probably have done it but did you follow the tuto provided by intellij idea ? https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/11/gulp-in-webstorm-9/

Comment: I had not, but I just followed it all to make sure I did not miss anything, and there was nothing I hadn't already done. So back to square one :-\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gulp run configuration is not supposed to be used for Node application debugging - it was designed to run/debug Gulp tasks. To debug your Node.js application, you need to create a `Node.js Run` configuration and specify the `.js` file generated by Gulp build as a file to debug.

If you still prefer using Gulp to start your server, make sure that it is started with `-debug-brk` and then use `Node.js Remote` run configuration to attach the debugger.

Like:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

gulp.task('server', function (cb) {
  exec('node --debug-brk=5858 app.js', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
...
```

run your `server` task, then create `Node.js Remote` run configuration and hit **Debug**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think that is exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for taking so long on this, I've been swamped up until today. So you are suggesting that I run as nodejs. That means I have to restart the server whenever I make a server side code change, right? I was under the impression gulp was there so I didn't have to restart the server on code changes? Or am I incorrect?

Comment: Gulp itself does nothing to restart your server/hotswap changes, so I'm not sure what your impression is based on... When using Node.js, you can use Live Edit to get changes hotswapped without server restart (if it's possible) or get server auto-restarted. Please see https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/08/live-edit-updates-in-webstorm-9/.
Make sure to set 'Update' in Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Live Edit to 'Auto in (ms)' and enable 'Restart if hotswap fails'